# Working ADAL code breaks in Oreo 8.0

Tags: azure, active-directory, adal

Am using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to authenticate

Upgraded Android to 8.0, same code still works fine in iOS

On Android, the only change I had to make was to the Custom Renderer required to handle the AAD login  when I got a 'deprecated' message, so I added this

This is the custom page renderer for Android

```
    public AuthRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    Views.Auth page;


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {

        System.Console.WriteLine("Debug: Loaded the page renderer");
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        page = e.NewElement as Views.Auth;


        var activity = this.Context as Activity;
        page.platformParameters = new PlatformParameters(activity);
        page.platformParameters.ToString();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Platform P " + page.platformParameters.ToString());


    }
```

This is the code snippet used to get the token

```
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        PlatformParameters p = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, hwnd);

        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectURI, p);

        Resource = https://[mywebsite].azurewebsites.net/api/Timekeeper
```

however, the code now simply fails to return a token in the way it used to on 7.1 and still does on iOS

Attached the output from the window in Visual Studio if someone could please review and see if anything jumps out?

```
[] 2018-03-01T14:22:11.6337440Z: 03e9fa3d-adae-45e8-bb97-0259fab9222b - LoggerBase.cs: Loading from cache.

[] 2018-03-01T14:22:11.6597470Z: 03e9fa3d-adae-45e8-bb97-0259fab9222b - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...

[] 2018-03-01T14:22:11.6752130Z: 03e9fa3d-adae-45e8-bb97-0259fab9222b - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache

[zygote] Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB

[zygote] After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB

[zygote] Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB

[WebViewFactory] Loading com.android.chrome version 58.0.3029.125 (code 303012512)

[cr_LibraryLoader] Time to load native libraries: 5 ms (timestamps 5331-5336)

[chromium] [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(140)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0

[cr_LibraryLoader] Expected native library version number 
"58.0.3029.125", actual native library version number "58.0.3029.125"

[cr_BrowserStartup] Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false

[cr_ChildProcLauncher] Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, inSandbox = true

[zygote] Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=46KB

[zygote] After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=46KB

[zygote] Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

[zygote] JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

[] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8c67c780, tid 999

[EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x8c607bc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x8c607bc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8b45c550)

[] 2018-03-01T14:22:12.1121650Z: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - LoggerBase.cs: UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/OSR1.170901.056; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.125 Mobile Safari/537.36 PKeyAuth/1.0

[BluetoothAdapter] Bluetooth binder is null

[cr_LibraryLoader] Using linker:org.chromium.base.library_loader.ModernLinker

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x8dc4e2e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8db2eb70)

[] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x88feb980, tid 1118

[EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x88fec2a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x88fec2a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x88fcddd0)

[VideoCapabilities] Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

[cr_MediaCodecUtil] HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.

[cr_MediaCodecUtil] HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.

[chromium] [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

[EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x88fed080: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x88fed080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x88fcddd0)

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xa55843c0] -> System.Xml[0xb0be9640]: 6

[cr_Ime] updateState: type [0->4], flags [64], show [false], 

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

[chatty] uid=10093(u0_a93) com.microlise.GeoFenceLocator identical 18 lines

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

[cr_Ime] updateState: type [4->4], flags [64], show [true], 

[cr_Ime] updateState: type [4->4], flags [64], show [false], 

[cr_Ime] updateState: type [4->4], flags [64], show [false], 

[chatty] uid=10093(u0_a93) com.microlise.GeoFenceLocator identical 5 lines

[cr_Ime] updateState: type [4->4], flags [64], show [false], 

[zygote] Do full code cache collection, code=121KB, data=82KB

[zygote] After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=54KB

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

[zygote] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Comment: The code you provide and the log output doesn't seem to contain any ADAL code or messages. Please provide the code, and more details about the errors that you receive.

Comment: Apologies, code snippet added

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, exactly the same except that i'm having a lot of fail in founding the token in the cache

```
05-02 11:48:14.900 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9002390Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started: 
05-02 11:48:14.900 I/        (22473):   CacheType: null
05-02 11:48:14.900 I/        (22473):   Authentication Target: User
05-02 11:48:14.900 I/        (22473):   , Authority Host: login.microsoftonline.com
05-02 11:48:14.901 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9014030Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Loading from cache.
05-02 11:48:14.903 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9031280Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.904 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9037160Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
05-02 11:48:14.904 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9042730Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.907 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9047280Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
05-02 11:48:14.907 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9074180Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.908 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9078860Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
05-02 11:48:14.908 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9085600Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.909 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9091330Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
05-02 11:48:14.910 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9099840Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.911 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9107730Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
05-02 11:48:14.912 V/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9117930Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
05-02 11:48:14.913 I/        (22473): 2018-05-02T09:48:14.9125770Z: 18184aeb-e84c-4942-8b09-c1578be3e24f - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
```

After a lot of research i've found my solution. ADAL in UWP project was working, same thing on iOS... So the problem must be on android...

In the MainActivity.cs file of the android project i had heedlessly commented out the below row from the OnActivityResult overridden method.

```
AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
```

So, the entire code of that method will now look like this:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Hope this help someone!